# Unable to write spark dataframe to azure blob storage at CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob (Error: Task failed while writing rows to wasbs://)

Tags: apache-spark

Need your help on the configuration for spark with azure blob storage (gen 1). We wanted to write parquet files from spark dataframe. I went through stackoverflow and other sources before reaching out here. I did some many issue reported in the past, but none were constructive feedback solve the issue. Appreciate for any feedback.

Our configuration:

- Spark 3.4.1
- Hadoop 3.3.4
- OpenJdk@17
- Pyspark 3.4.1
- Python 3.10.6

Spark Jars"

- hadoop-azure:3.3.4,
- com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.2

Here is the code:

```
azure_fs_spark_jars = "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.4,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.2,com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4"


# Configuration setup
conf = SparkConf() \
        .setAppName("Event Driven Spark - Blob Storage") \
        .setMaster("k8s://https://api.myk8s.org:6443") \
        .set("spark.jars.packages", azure_fs_spark_jars) \
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem") \
        .set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem") \
        .set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem") \
        .set("fs.azure.account.key.%s.blob.core.windows.net" % (account_name), account_key) \
        .set("fs.azure.account.key.%s.dfs.core.windows.net" % (account_name), account_key)

# Initialize Spark session with the above configuration
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

# Additional Hadoop configurations can be set like this:

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.key.%s.dfs.core.windows.net" % (account_name), account_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.key.%s.blob.core.windows.net" % (account_name), account_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.hadoop.fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")

print('\nSpark Version: ', sc.version) 
print('Spark Application ID: ', sc.applicationId)
```

... below example we were attempting to write csv to blob storage.

```
blob_path_out = f"DELETEME-Test-{random_int}"

output_path = "wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s" % (container_name, account_name, blob_path_out)

try:
    # Define write options
    format_option = 'csv'
    header_option = True
    mode_option = 'overwrite'
    
    limited_df \
      .coalesce(1) \
      .write.format(format_option) \
      .option('header', header_option) \
      .mode(mode_option) \
      .save(output_path)
    print(f"Data successfully written to: {output_path}")
    
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred while writing the DataFrame to Azure Blob Storage: {str(e)}")

finally:
    # Any cleanup or final operations can go here if needed
    pass
```

Output:

```
Spark Version:  3.4.1
Spark Application ID:  spark-866607cf96f7430ca2d343178ce7a642
                                                                                                                                                                                             
                SUCCESS: Count of Spark Dataframe rows loading Azure Blob storage parquet file Demo: 7170230


23/08/10 01:41:44 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job e0ffc0ed-2879-45d5-86e2-7a76e3d70f33.                                                                                     (0 + 1) / 1]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Authorized committer (attemptNumber=0, stage=6, partition=0) failed; but task commit success, data duplication may happen. reason=ExceptionFailure(org.apache.spark.SparkException,[TASK_WRITE_FAILED] Task failed while writing rows to wasbs://pis-data@dautpisdfs.blob.core.windows.net/DELETEME-Test-8745.,[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@12225e77,org.apache.spark.SparkException: [TASK_WRITE_FAILED] Task failed while writing rows to wasbs://pis-data@dautpisdfs.blob.core.windows.net/DELETEME-Test-8745.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:788)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:420)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.WriteFilesExec.$anonfun$doExecuteWrite$1(WriteFiles.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:888)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:888)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2898)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2770)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$FolderRenamePending.execute(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.rename(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:3337)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:571)
        at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.$anonfun$commitTask$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:51)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:640)
        at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.$anonfun$commit$1(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:640)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:404)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1563)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:410)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:196)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopy(CloudBlob.java:791)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopy(CloudBlob.java:740)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopy(CloudBlob.java:697)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopy(CloudBlob.java:660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:434)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2837)
```